# Segmentation fault with nested strtok possibly?

Tags: c

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sentence {
  char *words[8];
  struct sentence *next;
};

void read_sentence(struct sentence *head, char *words) {
    struct sentence *temp, *pointer;
    temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    pointer = head; 
    int i = 0;
    char *delimiter = " ";
    char *word = strtok(words, delimiter);
    while (word != NULL) {
      temp -> words[i++] = word;
      word = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
    while (pointer -> next) {
      pointer = pointer -> next;
    }
    pointer -> next = temp;
}

struct sentence *split_sentences(char *buf) {
  struct sentence *head;
  head = malloc(sizeof *head);
  head -> next = NULL;
  char *delimiter = ".";
  char *splitted = strtok(buf, delimiter);
  while (splitted != NULL) {
    read_sentence(head, splitted);
    splitted = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  }
  return head;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct sentence *iter = split_sentences("foo   bar. baz qux");
}
```

What this code essentially does is it parses an input (`"foo   bar. baz qux"`) and then it constructs a linked list of sentences using the `struct sentence` which should have reference to the words within each sentence along with a reference to the next sentence.

Here's the valgrid output:

```
 Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
 Command: ./a.out


 Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400741
    at 0x4EDAB9D: strtok_r (strtok_r.c:72)
    by 0x400635: split_sentences (in /home/C/a.out)
    by 0x4006A0: main (in /home/C/a.out)
```

It looks like there's an issue with the nested strtok?

Comment: Apart from the problem with literal strings as mentioned in Ctx's answer, you can get problems with your nested use. `strtok` uses a static buffer. You should use `strtok_r` if you want to use it in nested functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the string. From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html#BUGS):

> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

But here

```
split_sentences("foo   bar. baz qux");
```

you do exactly that. Try the same on a mutable string buffer, for example with

```
split_sentences(strdup("foo   bar. baz qux"));
```

Furthermore, you might indeed need to use `strtok_r()`, because you are interleaving `strtok()`-calls with two different buffers. This will not lead to a segmentation fault, but yields incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is not reentrant because it stores some state information in a static `char *` variable. (Think about it: when the first parameter is `NULL`, it continues where it left off on the original first parameter, so it needs to store the position where it left off somewhere.)

POSIX.1-2001 and later defines a re-entrant alternative to `strtok` called `strtok_r` which stores its state information in storage provided by the caller. `strtok_r` is not part of the C standard, but should be available on a POSIX.1-2001 compatible system.

Looking at your Valgrind output, it mentions `strtok_r`, so presumably the C library implementation of `strtok` is using `strtok_r` internally on your system. Therefore, you should be able to use it in your program.

```
void read_sentence(struct sentence *head, char *words) {
    struct sentence *temp, *pointer;
    temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    pointer = head; 
    int i = 0;
    char *saveptr;
    char *delimiter = " ";
    char *word = strtok_r(words, delimiter, &saveptr);
    while (word != NULL) {
      temp -> words[i++] = word;
      word = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &saveptr);
    }
    while (pointer -> next) {
      pointer = pointer -> next;
    }
    pointer -> next = temp;
}

struct sentence *split_sentences(char *buf) {
  struct sentence *head;
  head = malloc(sizeof *head);
  head -> next = NULL;
  char *saveptr;
  char *delimiter = ".";
  char *splitted = strtok_r(buf, delimiter, &saveptr);
  while (splitted != NULL) {
    read_sentence(head, splitted);
    splitted = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &saveptr);
  }
  return head;
}
```

Both `strtok` and `strtok_r` modify the buffer containing the string being split. Therefore, you cannot use them on a string literal because string literals are stored in a *non-modifiable*, anonymous array of `char`. Therefore, you need to change your `main` function to pass a *modifiable* array of `char` to `split_sentences`.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char sentences[] = "foo   bar. baz qux";
    struct sentence *iter = split_sentences(sentences);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest `strtok()` calls, as it maintains internal state, used to follow next strings in its first parameter.

If you need to nest `strtok()` calls in several loop levels, first execute a loop with the first string to get a list of pointers to extracted parts... then iterate that list to use `strtok(3)` on those strings... get more and more arrays, then iterate all those arrays to further split the input string.